# Non-negativity of invariant polynomials

Tags: reference-request, real-algebraic-geometry

Certifying the non-negativity of a symmetric polynomial is much easier than 
certifying the non-negativity of an arbitrary polynomial function: 
for instance, in (1) is proved that the complexity of deciding if a symmetric polynomial 
$f \in \mathbb{R}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ of fixed degree is non-negative grows only polynomially with $n$. 
This is in contrast to the general case which complexity is NP-hard already in the case of quartic forms (2).

Say that a polynomial is $G$-invariant if it is invariant under all actions of a linear group $G$.
Are there any other results that reduces the complexity of deciding if a fixed degree $G$-invariant polynomial is non-negative for $G \ne S_{n}$?

(1): Riener, Cordian. "[Symmetric semi-algebraic sets and non-negativity of symmetric polynomials.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0699)" arXiv preprint [arXiv:1409.0699] (2014).

(2): Murty, Katta G., and Santosh N. Kabadi. "[Some NP-complete problems in quadratic and nonlinear programming.](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~murty/np.pdf)" Mathematical programming 39.2 (1987): 117-129.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent paper (as of 1st February 2015) it is proved that the non-negativity of homogeneous forms invariant under the reflection group defined by a root system $\Phi \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ can be reduced to verifying the non-negativity of these forms in the union of the hyperplanes perpendicular to the elements of $\Phi$ [link].

Two examples of applications of this theorem are given in the paper:

- A symmetric form $F$ of degree $2d < 2n$ is nonnegative if and only if it is so on the hyperplanes $x_i - x_j = 0$;
- An even symmetric form of degree $2d < 4n$ is nonnegative if and only if it is so on the hyperplanes defined by $x_i = 0$ and by $\pm x_i \pm x_j=0$ for $1 \le i \ne j \le n$.

The paper is:

> Jose Acevedo and Mauricio Velasco, *Test Sets for Nonnegativity of Polynomials Invariant under a Finite Reflection Group.* arXiv preprint [arXiv:1502.00252](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00252) (2015).